# Failed to initialize Translation Service Error - Angular

Tags: angular, testing, service

I am trying to run test cases for my application. I have used i18n service which I have used for my component for translation purpose. When trying to run the code it gives `ERROR: Failed to initialize translation service`.

Here is my code for `model.ts file`

```
export class Model {

  constructor() {}

  public get tableModel(): TableModel {
    return this._tableModel;
  }

  public async initTranslationService(): Promise<boolean> {
    return await this.initTranslation();
  }


  public initTranslation(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      labelsArr.forEach((labelVal) => {
        promiseArr.push(this.translateService.stream(labelVal[9]));
      });

      Run(promiseArr).subscribe((results) => {
        if (this.translateService.getData().length >= 1) {
          results.forEach((labelTranslation, i) => {
          //some logic
          });
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to initialise translation service');
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }


}
```

I need help trying to solve this error. I have tried to look into and try to solve this error by making changes in `initTranslation  function`. But I am not sure what is the issue. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thie error is logged by your own code, when `this.translateService.getLangs().length >= 1` is false. Is it normal to log that error when this condition is false? If so, why is it false. Start an anlysis. We can't answer these questions for you.

Comment: Yes you are right I tried to figure that out. Do you have any more suggestions? Bit stuck here

Comment: are you getting any other console error? has translateModule been configured properly in your app module?